# No more compiling on WinEdt 9

Tags: winedt

Since one hour - without any change in my installation of WinEdt 9 (Windows 7 64 bits) - the process refuses to compile! I get a Console Running, but all operations stop after the language enumeration.
I need to type X to finish this. The last word is: 'Process has been killed'.

I tried to reboot the PC, then to reinstall Miktex (basic-miktex-2.9.5105-x64),  without success...

Any idea where the bug is?

I may have to reinstall WinEdt, but I will wait for your answers if any... Thank you

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\begin{document} 
    Et voila 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally neither miktex nor winedt is not at fault, but some error in your tex file. Try to compile on the command line to get some better error messages and a log-file.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It is likely that you introduced an error into your document. A good method to find it is called [prepariing a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: Here is my code: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Et voila
\end{document}   No compiling!

Comment: Since MikTeX installs TeXworks, you can test compile there.  If it compiles, then the problem in likely in WinEdt 9.  If it will not compile, then create a new MWE.  `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hi\end{document}`  Now if this does not compile then something has happened to your Miktex installation.   I trust your Miktex installation was either done as `admin` or you are logged into the same account as it was installed in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error arose because of an issue not reported in the posting itself and was resolved by a measure not hinted at in the posting.